# Extra padding / space under h1 element in safari on iphone 5, 7.1.2

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, padding

Im having a problem with spacing appearing on iphone/safari underneath my h1 elements. The buttons on my page also share this problem in safari.

Have tried vertical-align: bottom, and setting all kinds of paddings for the h1 to 0px. I know i could fix this with a negative margin or a padding like 15px 10px 10px 10px, but there must be some way to figure out whats getting added to the h1 in safari and get rid of it :)

Hope someone else can point me in the right direction.

**Here are some pictures (not allowed to upload pics cause of my newness):**

- How i want it to look (and how it looks on desktop in i.e. Google
  Chrome):

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7YWA.jpg
- How it looks in Safari:

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0DoT.png

**Link to test site:**

davidpetersson.nu/test

I've done researching all day on this matter, but i havent found anything. I hope my description is good enough and that i dont offend anyone since im new at this:)

Keep on rockin!

Comment: have you tried this `html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }`

Comment: Tried it but for the body element in my css. Changing to the html element, did no difference :/ Thnx for a quick answer though

Comment: could you please share the code, with the working example in fiddle?

Comment: if you have used @media type check the padding for the header.

Comment: you can see the code here: http://www.davidpetersson.nu/test